# PHP pie chart not splitting up into slices

Tags: javascript, php

Hi I am new to PHP programming and I'm having an error with my pie chart. It would not split into different slices and only shows 1 slice showing 100%.

This is my code for the piechart:

```
<?php // for piechart ?>
<script>
    $( document ).ready( function() {

        var data = [
            [ 'Close to Signoff',
              <?php echo $project_status[5]; ?>],['Complete',    <?php echo $project_status[4]; ?>], ['In Progress', <?php echo $project_status[3]; ?>], 
            ['Overdue', <?php echo $project_status[2]; ?>],['Pending', <?php echo $project_status[1]; ?>]
          ];

           var plot1 = jQuery.jqplot ('chart1', [data], 
            { 
              seriesDefaults: {
                // Make this a pie chart.
                renderer: jQuery.jqplot.PieRenderer, 
                rendererOptions: {
                  // Put data labels on the pie slices.
                  // By default, labels show the percentage of the slice.
                  showDataLabels: true
                }
              }, 
              legend: { show:true, location: 'e' }
            }
          );
    } );
</script>
```

Am I doing anything wrong?

Comment: Which error do you get?

Comment: 1) check source, if `var data = [ ... ]` has proper values
2) check if all script plugins included (jqplot.pieRenderer.min.js)

Answer (score 0):

When the graph is shown, the only reason should be inside `data` variable.

To avoid setting empty (or not set) values use:

```
printf("%d",$project_status[0]);
```

instead of

```
echo $project_status[0];
```

printf will place `0` in case of empty value what can be problem when setting the JS variable.